# How to create and pass a generic type to a function at the call site?

Tags: typescript

In order to assert on an unknown type, I'm trying to use the standard generic type declaration syntax at the callsite,

But it's linting in a couple places:

```
// record is annoted to `unknown` above this snippet

runThis <GenericRecord extends { prop1: number }> (record as GenericRecord);

/*
Cannot find name 'GenericRecord'.ts(2304)

'?' expected.ts(1005)
*/
```

I see nothing about creating a generic at the point of invocation. But I need to assert a generic type on `record`` and don't know any other way to do it.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Here is the declaration for `runThis`

```
function runThis<Record extends { seconds: number }>(record: Record): Record | void {
  if (record.seconds >= 4) return record;
}
```

Comment: can you share the signature of `runThis` ?

Comment: @PritamKadam ok, I have added the full declaration above

Comment: `runThis<{ prop1: number, seconds: number }>(record);` ? Or `runThis(record as { prop1: number, seconds: number });`

Comment: Yes that concrete type would work I think, but is there a way to allow objects of any shape, including the two important keys, to be passed? That would be a more flexible solution.

Comment: Using that will allow you to pass in any object that that has _at least_ those two keys.